# Aging Q&As and Fresh Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Here is the basic problem that I am running into over and over. I have a question that I would like to find an answer to on Stack Exchange. As I search I find a number of promising Q&As in the system that are effectively duplicates of my question. So far so good.

When I go through the answers I realize that every answer is many years old and refers to a version of the language that I am no longer using. Bumping the question or trying to get it more attention is not specifically useful in this case because the answers it already has are perfectly good and well-accepted answers in the context of when it was asked.

Despite the answers being good, it is likely there are much better ways to address the problem with a more modern version of the language. Additionally, perspectives change over time, best practices at that time may have been very different from now.

By just bumping and encouraging extensions to the old answer we are creating a confusing mix of old and new answers. More importantly, good new answers to very old questions are unlikely to receive the votes or attention the deserve when they are competing against a top rated answer with years of upvotes.

I want to be a good Stack Exchange citizen and not post duplicate questions, but the answers as they currently stand do not address the capabilities of more up to date programming languages and there doesn't seem to be a solid way to re-pose the question in a more up to date context without being overwhelmed with duplicate question tags.

Is there a suggestion to handle this situation?

I also wanted to put out the idea that it may be helpful to have a mechanism that depreciates Q&As without a freshly accepted answer for X period of time. I am specifically not suggesting they get deleted, but that we should be more accepting of questions that are duplicates or very similar to old depreciated Q&As.

Another helpful item would be some indication of the age of a Q&A. I realize that the dates are on every post, but the information is not easy to see when you are searching for answers.

I am not trying to upset the system here, but I think it would be worthwhile discussing ways to make the information contained in these sites more timely and relevant.

> I am getting a lot of pushback on this either not being an issue or I
>   should just follow advice to edit the old question to reflect new
>   technology. Based on this I would like to understand if anyone sees
>   this as a problem. So I am going to ask some questions directly;
>
> Does anyone see a problem with old Q&As stagnating and not getting
>   updated with new answers that reflect current technology?
>
> Does anyone feel it would be better to have a system that facilitates
>   or encourages new answers to old Q&As so that we have information that
>   better reflects current programming standards and technologies?

This Question has a discussion tag in the hope that we could have a discussion on the topic. I am still hoping that will happen, but if no one else sees the problem I can refocus on something else. My goal wasn't to post a question that has a bunch of people voting it down.

Comment: Although the duplicate sounds like it does not address already answered questions I think its [highest voted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/215590) addresses both unanswered and answered (but outdated) just as well.

Comment: @Poly how old is that answer? Sorry, it was too tempting. I read your link and the answer does touch on similar concepts, but the questions are very different. I would like to keep this as  a separate question and specifically  would like to have the opportunity to discuss the proposals which are not addressed in either that question or answer you refer to.

Comment: Nathan, this is a good example of what I am hoping to discuss. The duplicate you point to is from 2011. At that time, this wasn't as big a problem as it is now. Stack Overflow wasn't as mature and answers were not as old. I don't think the question you refer to would get the same answer. Maybe I am wrong, but I would like the opportunity to see.

Comment: Just because answers are old does not mean that they cannot be refreshed via editing; they can be edited by anyone. New answers can usually be added by anyone too; exceptions are protected, locked, closed questions.

Comment: That could work, but what happens when a question is updated to focus on new technology but the long time accepted answers no longer apply to the reformed question.
This also doesn't address the very real problem of getting fresh answers on an old question with a highly accepted answer. Editing the question doesn't make the accepted answer go away.

Comment: I am raising this question because this is a very real problem for me right now. Many of the C# focused questions I am seeking answers on seem to be stagnating. The old answers seem to be preventing the discussion of new solutions.

Comment: My experience in SO's Java tags is that plenty of "here's how you do it in Java 7/8/9" answers are being posted on old questions.  I've posted some myself, and they do get votes.  Sure, some readers may not read past the top answer, but that's their loss.

Comment: The issue I am seeing may be specific to C#. That is the area I am focused on and I can't legitimately comment outside my experience. From my point of view, I am reading everything. It is a serious lack of new answers that is the problem. From your comment, I can only assume that Java programmers are better at updating old questions. When I do find a new answer that is valuable I am more than happy to upvote it. But that seems rare.

Comment: If accepted answers are creating a ceiling that newer answers cannot break through then this proposal could help: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/keeping-special-status-for-accepted-answers-without-sticking-them-to-top-forever

Comment: My general proposal was to allow old answers to be depreciated (not deleted) and allow people to post new, similar questions focused on new technology without the fear their question would arbitrarily be voted a duplicate. I think that would allow questions to have a fresh start without the overhang of extremely old answers blocking them.

Comment: I don't see that proposal being discussed in any of the other questions or the answers attributed to them. I would much rather have someone put up a counter-argument to this idea than this question just being thrown away as a duplicate. If it would help I can re-edit the question again.
I am finding it frustrating to get shut out of a discussion in Meta. I though this was specifically the place to discuss ideas.

Comment: PolyGeo Yes, that could help. It is a good idea. I wish you would put an answer in referring to it as an alternative instead of voting to close my question.