# Make the date of answer more prominent

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting

Say a question has many answers. The typical user is not going to read all of them. Instead, they will naturally looks only at the accepted answer (if any) and perhaps a few of the mostly highly-voted answers.

And so if the newest answer happens to be better than all existing answers, it will probably not be read, because it languishes near the bottom.

I'm not sure what the solution to this is. But I think it would be great to alert users to the fact that an answer is relatively new (and thus hasn't had much opportunity to be upvoted). Right now the date of the answer is small and at the bottom right, together with the user name, where it is not very prominent.

A possibility is to **place the date  of answer just under the vote count** (and the upvote/downvote buttons). Or if the community feels there's not enough space and that'd be too much clutter, even just placing the year there would be great.

Answer (score 2):

No.

That would be highly confusing and just wrong as design choice. (In my opinion.)

If users are interested to see newer answers first, there is already such an option:

> [image]

The accepted answer will still be first, but those after it will be displayed sorted by last activity.

However, I do agree that the current sort is lacking, and new good answers might not get the attention they deserve. There is really no magic solution for  this, but worth to mention that SE staff [are aware of that and looking for ways to change this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5000038#5000038).

Comment: I think having accepted but not most upvoted answers not be at top forever would help in at least some cases: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268666/215590