# Accepted answer is low scoring - Would SE benefit from a "contentious" banner-alert?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

With respect to [Is it safe to cut off from the inside of my helmet?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/49886/19705)

This question is a good example of SE working suboptimally.  The accepted answer presently has a score of -1 with 4 up and 5 downvotes.

I suspect OP has selected this answer because it matches their original anticipated answer, where 3 answers boil down to "no don't do it" and 3 reduce to "yes its okay"

So after reading all answers, there's no clear-cut answer.

Related but not dupes:

- [How to deal with an accepted answer that seems completely incorrect?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/)

**Should the question be marked somehow to show there is no consensus**  and that the reader should read the whole body of answers, not just the accepted one.

---

Originally [asked in meta.bicycles](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/)  and some good points came up there

- The purpose of flags is to classify the question not judge it.
- Tags go on the question not the answer

Comment: What's the end goal of flagging here? Flagging is for things you want mods to take a look at and I don't see what's actionable about people disagreeing

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  "flagging" might be an overloaded word here - perhaps I mean "banner alert"  similar to the one that shows a question is protected.  The point is to highlight that there is no consensus, or that the accepted answer may not be a good answer, nor representative of the stack community's opinions.     Its quite unusual to have a negative-score accepted answer.

Comment: ah, post notice?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek possibly - something to indicate that the hive-mind is not in agreement and that the future reader should read all the answers and make a decision, not just read the accepted answer. I do like PolyGeo's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the undesirable answer ordering on [Is it safe to cut off from the inside of my helmet?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/is-it-safe-to-cut-off-from-the-inside-of-my-helmet) where the accepted answer, currently with a net score of -1, appears before another answer currently with a net score of +9, is a classic example of where the implementation of [Keeping special status for Accepted Answers without sticking them to top forever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666) would enable this situation to sort itself out over time.

If that were implemented then the amber checkmark, once triggered, would act as a warning that the negatively voted answer might be accepted (and would appear to have helped the question asker) but should be used with caution.

In the meantime your community could apply more downvotes to the contentious answer because a high net negative score would surely have people treating an answer with caution, and might lead to the answerer self-deleting their post.

Comment: I like that - good idea.   The question in question is basically a yes/no.

Comment: @Criggie DVing that answer because you prefer the other answer is not fair either, as that -1 answer seem wrote by a high rep user. No one left a comment in that answer too. I suspect there is no consensus because there is no know facts that back either claims, as such it could be simply offtopic as primary opinion based.