# Do we avoid questions about current events that have a limited life?

Tags: support, close-reasons, moderation, help-center, scope

RPG Stack Exchange, along with a few other older sites, have this bullet point in [our on-topic FAQ](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - We don't want the information on our site to become obsolete, and so we try not to ask questions whose answers may change with time. This means we don't re-ask the same question once it's been answered, we keep adding to the previous question.

This isn't site-specific policy — this bullet point was added in 2013 by a CM [along with the launch of the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center). This launch was also contemporaneous with [the removal of the Too Localized close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons).

Sometimes RPG Stack Exchange gets questions about the state of release of specific content or products: whether they're still in testing, whether they're out, when the release date is if it's known, etc. Recently one of these questions was closed by my fellow moderator with the following reason:

> I'm closing this question because “is it out yet?” questions have a limited life: they either get obsolete answers (before it's out) or become obsolete themselves (after it's out). RPG.SE is for “forever” questions, not current events.

When I asked them about this, they pointed back to that above Help Center bullet point. We don't agree it means we should close this kind of question though. Their stance is as stated there. Mine is that we can't be for just “forever” questions: questions can naturally have their answers change over time as new content gets released, and it's fine to handle release date questions and answer them then let them become obsolete.

Our users have already started exploring site-specific policy, but we're both interested in finding out what the state of network-wide policy is:

**Is that bullet point quoted at the top still a relevant network policy? Is it outdated? Was/is it meant to imply we only ask “forever” questions, and avoid questions which may inevitably become irrelevant/obsolete, such as asking about state of release and release dates?**

Comment: I think all questions should be timeless rather than time constrained w.r.t. usefulness.  I agree with your fellow moderator on this.

Answer (score 10):

I guess the big problem with "is it out yet" question is it's both too narrow (there's 3 answers possible, yes, no, never) and too broad — in the sense that it fails the "practical problem to be solved" test.

The Q&A format's terrible for keeping a nose out for release dates — "When's windows 10 ver 12345" going to get released would get closed in a shake of a dog's tail on Super User.

The *only* people with a definitive answer for "questions about the state of release of specific content or products" are the folks that make the game, and SE functions poorly as a replacement for them communicating clearly to their customers.

IMO your fellow moderator's close reason feels like common sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are very few sites that genuinely restrict themselves to "forever" questions - technology changes, culture changes, laws change, scientific discoveries are made - the sands that most sites are being built on are themselves slowly shifting.

However, questions whose answers are inevitably going to change (possibly multiple times) over a short timescale seem to present a much greater problem than those that might slowly age. even if no-one cares about the unstable basis on which voting would take place, what mechanism would there be to ensure that the answer (and maybe question) got updated at points when it needed to? Some users might be conscientious about updating answers, but overall it seems like asking for unnecessary trouble.

Comment: If the "unstable basis on which voting would take place" includes old accepted answers being stuck at the top forever then this Meta Q&A may be worth reviewing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/keeping-special-status-for-accepted-answers-without-sticking-them-to-top-forever