# What is the goal of "accepted answer mark"

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

As in [Would it be possible to have a "community accepted" feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature), votes can already mark better answer (though not always work especially when there are a lot of answers).

Then except for giving asker 2 reps and answerer 15 reps, are there other benefits (BTW are the 2 and 15 reps really a benefit for the site?) of this feature?

Obviously "mark an answer right or wrong" is not a benefit, since a feature like "tag any answer as right/wrong" will do a better job.

Comment: The goal is for the OP to signal *This answer helped me solve my question best*. In an extreme case the reasoning of an OP to accept an answer can be *This is answer is so wrong that I finally understand how I should solve the problem stated in my question*. We hope that reasoning isn't followed too often as many visitors presume the accept mark signals correctness.

Answer (score 2):

The principal benefit is that the accepted answer, when accepted by a user other than the answerer, gets pinned to the top.

This means that it will usually be the answer first read, and if useful, often upvoted.  Consequently, the 15 points for being accepted may be negligible in comparison to later upvotes.

Personally, I do not think that they should be pinned to the top forever, because better answers may come later, and not be seen by the asker (who may have ceased using the site).  For that I have proposed [Keeping special status for Accepted Answers without sticking them to top forever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/keeping-special-status-for-accepted-answers-without-sticking-them-to-top-forever)