# Getting attention for answers that have aways been incorrect

Tags: support, answers, security, wrong-answers

There's a question about [what to do about outdated answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149032/what-should-we-do-when-highly-voted-accepted-answers-are-outdated-incorrect-and?noredirect=1&lq=1), but what if the answer is not outdated but was always incorrect and gave simply wrong information, or more seriously information that might lead to a serious insecurity in the Stack Exchange user's systems?

For the Server Fault question *["Securely add a host (e.g. GitHub) to the SSH known_hosts file"](https://serverfault.com/questions/856194/securely-add-a-host-e-g-github-to-the-ssh-known-hosts-file)* the two top answers are actually insecure.  They both involve using ssh-keyscan which is subject to a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) (it just downloads the first key it sees). The first and accepted answer does say "verify them manually" so technically it's not truly wrong, but since it doesn't explain how to do that it isn't really answering the question.

This is the top result on the Google search for the subject so it's important that the correct information is surfaced and made more visible.

I *do not want to flag the answers* since they don't seem to be malicious, so it's not appropriate. I've downvoted the others. How can I get a bit more attention from e.g. moderators to get the insecure answers made less prominent and more clearly warn people about them?

Comment: "Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies or an altogether wrong answer" - The handling of the accuracy of content is not the task of a moderator.

Comment: This has been marked as a duplicate of a question about outdated answers, however the wrong answers weren't outdated - simply insecure from the beginning.

Comment: @Loong thanksfor the comment - I wasn't trying to flag - it's a question about what *should I do* when flagging doesn't seem to be appropriate.  I tried to make my question clearer.  Does that help?

Comment: Raise the issue on the per-site meta and see if 20K-ers (users with delete privilege) agree with you. Also write a better answer so that can start gaining votes.

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/what-happens-when-an-accepted-answer-is-wrong-but-the-op-is-gone just replace *accepted* in that question with *highly voted*

Comment: In your shoes? I'd just post a better answer pointing out why the rest are wrong. its the best you can do

Comment: If you feel the answers are dangerous, and the solution to the problem will lead to insecure implementation, you should downvote the answer.  If everyone downvoted answers that were incomplete, incorrect, or insecure and then submitted complete, correct and secure the bad answers would be ignored or eventually deleted and would no longer be a problem.